# Issues importing tf Transform on cloud ml

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, tensorflow-transform

Whenever I try to import tensorflow-transform on an mlengine job I get the following issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"main", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 
15, in 
from tensorflow.contrib.boosted_trees.python.ops import quantile_ops
ImportError: No module named boosted_trees.python.ops
```

Tensorflow transform runs fine on dataflow but when I try to train the model the above error appears. Tensorflow in general seems to work fine on mlengine, but I do run into issues if I try to just import boosted_trees.python.ops. I'm using tf 1.4 and tft 0.4.0. The code that I am running is a slightly modified version of the cloudml-samples reddit_tft example.

Comment: Could you provide some details such as, whether or not you are passing --runtime-version=1.4 to your job, the contents of your setup.py, if you are using one, etc. I verified that the line that fails in your traceback works on my local machine with TF 1.4, so I'm suspecting your job is running an older version.

Answer (score 0):

AFAI the python package is 'tensorflow_transform' not 'tensorflow-transform'.
There is a conflict between 'tensorflow' and 'tensorflow_transform' in your code. I used tensorflow_transform version 0.5 and tensorflow 1.4.1  in reddit_tft example and it worked.